# Vertical Scroll not working. Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet that I am attempting to have a scroll bar show only 10 of the possible hundreds of items on a list. I created a scroll bar, had it reference a field, for calculations. Each field that the scroll bar interacts with is referenced off the field as well. So I can't imagine why it's not working.

What is happening is that when I scroll the bar up and down the text to the right of it doesn't move. I'd like to know if it is my computer, or not.  If it is my computer what would I need to do to make it work? I use VBA and I may of accidently disabled something to allow the scrolling to not work, but I don't know.

Can someone help please?

Here is the worksheet in question.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3327208/Excel/scrollnotworking.xlsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation is set to Manual.

Do this. Under the

`Formulas Tab` click on `Calculation Options` and then on `Automatic`

Now try it

[image]

**FOLLOWUP**

> sweet perfect, is there a way in VBA to make this happen? I have to go through my code and find out if there is a spot where makes this as Manual... because I think there is. – Matt Ridge 1 min ago

There are mainly two reasons why the calculation switches to manual via VBA

**1)** You set it `MANUAL` and then forget to set it back. For example

```
Sub Sample()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    '~~> Rest of your code
End Sub
```

**2)** You set it to `MANUAL` in the beginning and set it `AUTOMATIC` in the end but it still remains `MANUAL`. This primarily happens because you didn't include proper `Error Handling` because of which the code exits prematurely from the procedure. See this example

**The wrong way**

```
Sub Sample()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    '~~> Rest of your code

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

**The preferred way**

```
Sub Sample()
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    '~~> Rest of your code

Letscontinue:
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

**Note**: If you want, You can also store the current state of `Calculation` and set it back at the end of the code if you want to.

Comment: sweet perfect, is there a way in VBA to make this happen? I have to go through my code and find out if there is a spot where makes this as Manual... because I think there is.

Comment: Figured out where you had it, thanks again.  I'm wondering could this of been turned off by VBA with the scripts I've been working on? Would it be this: `Application.Calculation=xlCalculationAutomatic`

Comment: Again, thanks, you've helped out a lot, you actually just made sense upon one part of programming for me without realizing it too :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout There's another way that a workbook could be set to manual calculation: manually. And if you save a workbook in manual calculation, any workbook you open afterwards in the same session will revert to manual calculation regardless of how it was saved. [Description of how Excel determines the current mode of calculation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214395)

Comment: @JP: I was referring via VBA `There are mainly two reasons why the calculation switches to manual via VBA`